# Unable to use a custom domain to log in (SwiftlySalesforce)

Tags: ios, salesforce

When the user tries to log in and selects "Use custom domain" in the pop-up window and uses an authUrl like "test.salesforce.com", the flow continues normally but stops before the connected app requests necessary permissions and the window is dismissed before actually logging in.

I implemented the connection with Salesforce using version 10.0.1 of the package and the login using the Connection.authenticate() method like this:
Shop.shared.salesforceCredential = try await Shop.shared.salesforceConnection?.authenticate()

The user log in with custom domain.